# How to display Android UI via XML Layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, user-interface

Currently I understand I can create a XML Layout and pass that to setContentView(...), or I can pass a Customized view to setContentView(...).

But what if I want to combine the elements of both? Is it possible to use a layout first, then  to programmatically add to the UI via java code?

For example: How could I create a view that uses an Asset background picture with an added loading widget on top?

ADDED INQUIRY: Right now and I think of a View and a Layout as two things for setContentView to display. But can a View hold a layout within it to be displayed?

Comment: Is there a particular reason the image is in your assets folder instead of your drawable folder?

Comment: not at all, i didn't even know there's a different folder. What should go in assets and should go in drawable?

Comment: You would typically put images in the res/drawable folder so you can reference them by ID and pull them into your activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible to set an XML layout with setContentView(), and programmatically add more views/widget to that layout. Here's a short example.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/background_image">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/custom_content_root"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- This is where we will add views programmatically -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

TestActivity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
private LinearLayout mRoot;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the Linearlayout we want to add new content to..
    mRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.custom_content_root);

    // Create a TextView for example
    TextView moreText = new TextView(this);

    // Set the layout parameters of the new textview.
    moreText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    moreText.setText("More text :)");

    // Add the new textview to our existing layout
    mRoot.addView(moreText);
}
}
```

The result is an activity with background_image.png as background, and two textviews with text ;)

You can add any type of view (TextView, EditText, ImageView, Buttons etc) this way.

Comment: Should I create a XML Layout for each one of my screens in my application? How do I associate a screen with its XML layout?

Comment: When you say screen, you probably mean Activity. You usually create one XML layout for each Activity, and set it via setContentView().

Comment: When I say screen I mean for example: load screen, main screen, personal screen. How does one XML layout generalize for the entire app?

Comment: One XML layout does not usually generalize for the entire app, and what you call screens are in reality Activities.
Lets use your example:

That app would have 3 activities, one for each "screen". Lets call them LoadingActivity.java, MainActivity.java and PersonalActivity.java.

Each of the activities would have its own layout, loading_layout.xml, main_layout.xml and personal_layout.xml.

In the onCreate() method of each Activity, you would specify the correct layout for that activity with setContentView().

Comment: oh i didn't even know that an application could have more activities. In my mind an activity was an entry for starting the application. How do you link the activities in the scheme u described? This is the usual paradigm for android programs? Lastly, is there a way for me to give you points for your advice? thanks!

Comment: This is the usual paradigm for Android apps! You navigate between Activities using Intents, and the Activity method startActivity(Intent i). Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html There's a subsection explaining how to start a new Activity. You can give me points by checking the checkbox to the left of my answer.

Comment: okay thanks you very much for pointing me in the right way. So far I've been making everything in one activity. But, would a loading screen and a main screen be two activities? I don't know to what extent a code should be a separate activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to add widgets after using setContentView(). It's also possible to inflate XML layouts yourself using [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

You could add the loading widget to a layout that was defined inside your XML by getting it using findViewById and then using a method from [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html).